# Unable to access file from the Git submodule in GitLab-CI Job

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hello : I would like to request guidance w.r.t an issue that I'm facing.

I've 2 Repos, and the goal is refer a file from Repo#2 in Repo#1

Repo#1 - https://gitlab.xyz.com/ertm/search/housekeeper_job.git

Repo#2 - https://gitlab.xyz.com/ertm/gitlab-pipeline.git

I’ve defined the .gitmodule file as below inside the housekeeper_job (Repo#1) repository

```
[submodule "gitlab-pipeline"]
path = gitlab-pipeline
url = ../../gitlab-pipeline.git
```

In one of the stages in the .gitlab-ci.yml in the housekeeper_job repository,  I’m trying to invoke a file( script) residing in the gitlab-pipeline (Repo#2) repository.

source /ertm/gitlab-pipeline/pipeline.sh
pipeline.sh is the file which reside in gitlab-pipeline.git in the Root folder.

**Excerpt from the Output of the failed Pipeline job**

Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/ertm/search/housekeeper_job'...
Checking out 4fe7240d as feature/hkeeper...
Updating/initializing submodules recursively...
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
$ source /ertm/gitlab-pipeline/pipeline.sh
/bin/bash: line 87: /ertm/gitlab-pipeline/pipeline.sh: No such file or directory

- Version of gitlab-runner 11.2.0
- Version of Enterprise Gitlab 10.X

Can I know what I'm doing wrong or what step I'm missing here?.

Comment: I think you need to get your CI system to `git clone --recursive` or similar so that it checks our your submodule code.

Comment: @Hitobat, I've added  `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive` to gitlab-ci.yml.

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue . https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37356

Comment: You can tell this hasn't worked as the line `Updating/initializing submodules recursively...` ought to be followed by `submodule 'name' (https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.com/group/name) registered for path 'path'
Cloning into '/builds/...'...
Submodule path 'path': checked out 'GUID'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar problem by removing all submodules [as described here](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/) then using `git submodule add <repo> <path>`

`git submodule add` does more than just create a `.gitmodule` file.

Comment: This appears to be cargo-cult-ism, but allowing the local path to default, as in `git submodule add <repo>`, never worked for me.